# Webpack externals help needed

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-externals

I have created an application (using vue and webpack) that needs two urls to access REST services. These urls are different per deployment. So I would realy like to have an external configuration file (maybe JSON) that stores those urls.

I did some research and I came upon webpack externals. Added externals to my configuration file:

```
module.exports = {

...

  externals: {
    tryout: path.resolve(__dirname, "./test.js")
  }

}
```

test.js is really simple --> export default {url1 : 'https://bla', url2: 'https://bla2'}

From the vue file where I need this file I call:

```
import Tryout from 'tryout'

console.log(Tryout)
```

This causes my application to show a blank screen. No errors in the console nor in the npm console screen.

Not sure what is happening. couple of questions:

- I am using dev server not sure where to place the test.js file I placed it here : __dirname, "./test.js" so this is in my build directory...
- Should I load it in my index.html file like an external libary load?
- does anybody has a step by step example? Couldn`t find it online..

This should be simple but no clue since I am not getting any error or message...

Any help would be really helpful!

Comment: externals means "don't build these modules into the final output, the user will specify their own NPM module called "tryout"). What are you trying to achieve? It's normally used when you don't want to build in third party libraries such as Vue into a public library that will be consumed by people who already have Vue for example.

Comment: ah .. i think this is my problem... I need to create an npm module for this... I didn`t do that. I already couldn`t understand why the system knows 'jQuery' in this example: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/. Maybe there is another way to achive what I need.... I just need a file where I can specify 2 urls outside my packed app. I would like to distribute the app to my customers and these customers dhould change the urls to their needs...